# Modify variable for some observations

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to change the values of a variable called "`layer`" for some observations on R. I have a vector with the ID's of the observations that I want to modify:

```
> str(cell_black_communities)
List of 1
 $ : num [1:54984] 1776 1777 1778 1779 1782 ...
```

And a `data.frame` with the ID variable and a variable called "`layer`" that I want to modify. I tried the following code:

```
df$layer[df$ID %in% unlist(cell_black_communities)] <- -1 * (df$layer)
```

And actually the variable change:

```
> summary(df$layer)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 -62570   -2392    5353   18250   37200  144900
```

But a warning appear: `In df$layer[df$ID %in% : number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length`. I want to know why this warning appears and how can I solve it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You are currently trying to assign a vector the length of your dataset to a smaller vector, this will give you incorrect values. You could try something like `df$layer2 <- ifelse(df$ID %in% unlist(cell_black_communities),-1,1) * df$layer`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
df$layer_mod <- ifelse(df$ID %in% unlist(cell_black_communities), <here comes modification formula>, df$layer)
```

So if your modification consisted on adding 1 to layer, this wolud be:

```
df$layer_mod <- ifelse(df$ID %in% unlist(cell_black_communities), df$layer + 1, df$layer)
```

... and just on setting layer to -1

```
df$layer_mod <- ifelse(df$ID %in% unlist(cell_black_communities), -1, df$layer)
```

... changing sign of layer:

```
df$layer_mod <- ifelse(df$ID %in% unlist(cell_black_communities), -1 * df$layer, df$layer)
```

Obviously this creates a new column in df, but you could easily overwrite current layer column, by putting `df$layer` on the left side of assignment.